# S4: Use class attributes as default input values for class methods

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm new to S4 OO system in R. I'm thinking to use class attributes as default input into generic methods, but I got an error message saying that `argument "xxx" is missing, with no default`.

Basically I have a list of functions (i.e. class methods) which operate at the same set of class attributes. I wish to use these class attributes as the default input values to the list of functions, but the way I implemented (I used `definition = function(theObject, input = theObject@attribute1)`, see example code below) throws error... Why it's not working?

Many thanks in advance!

```
class1 = setClass("class1", 
                  slots = c(attribute1 = "numeric"), 
                  prototype = list(
                    attribute1 = NULL
                  ))

setGeneric(name = "method1", 
           def = function(theObject, input){
             standardGeneric("method1")
           })

setMethod(f = "method1", 
          signature = "class1", 
          definition = function(theObject, input = theObject@attribute1){
            theObject@attribute1 = input + 1
            return (theObject)
          })


x = class1() # instantiate an object from class1
x@attribute1 = 1 # set attribute value
method1(x, input = 2) # This works fine if I use "input = 2" explicitly

# This throws the following error "Error in method1(x) : argument "input" is missing, with no default"
# Even though in setMethod part I did specify the default value of input
method1(x)
```

Comment: have you tried, in your call to `setGeneric`, setting the signature to just be `theObject` rather than the default of both arguments? I'm not certain whether this will solve your issue, but it might (I believe all arguments in the signature are evaluated immediately on calling the generic, so a missing default error could arise there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this is the case, but in order to set a default for an input with `setMethod`, the generic requires a default as well. e.g.:

```
class1 = setClass("class1", 
                  slots = c(attribute1 = "numeric"), 
                  prototype = list(
                    attribute1 = NULL
                  ))

setGeneric(name = "method1", 
           def = function(theObject, input=NA){ #Setting any input here enables defaults for methods
             standardGeneric("method1")
           })

setMethod(f = "method1", 
          signature = "class1", 
          definition = function(theObject, input=1){
            theObject@attribute1 = input + 1
            return (theObject)
          })

x = class1() 
x@attribute1 = 1 
method1(x, input = 2) 
method1(x)
```

Comment: If you figure out why does it happen, please update the answer. I was looking for an explanation in both S4 and S3 classes documentation and I still don't understand it :).

Comment: I think the reason is that argument matching occurs for the generic itself (which fails because there is no generic default for `input`), and then happens again for the method. Why *that* is, I can offer no explanation though.